# Error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.60 (magfieldmapper_gui)

Tags: 20.04, shared-library

I am very new to ubuntu and when I tried to run the `magfieldmapper_gui` by xsens, it throws me this error.

```
$ ./magfieldmapper_gui
 
./magfieldmapper_gui: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I googled a lot but I could not find a solution. Can Someone please point out what I'm doing wrong or the solution for this error.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is "magfieldmapper_gui by xsens"? From where it was downloaded?

Comment: I am sorry, My ubuntu version is 20.04. Magfieldmapper is an GUI which helps us to calibrate and use IMU's with ROS from a company called xsens.

http://wiki.ros.org/xsens_mti_driver
https://www.xsens.com/software-downloads

Answer (score 4):

The mentioned *`libicui18n.so.60`* library was contained in [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libicui18n.so.60) for 18.04 LTS.

You can download and install it manually on 20.04 LTS using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
```

and then retry to run `./magfieldmapper_gui`.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert. It works like a charm